# Eclipse RCP: add files into newly created project

Tags: file, eclipse-plugin, copy, eclipse-rcp, wizard

I am new to Eclipse RCP development, but have read about and tutorials.
I have open source project [NodeEclipse-1](https://github.com/PaulVI/nodeclipse-1/), I'd like to add 2 files (README.md & hello-world-server.js) into newly created project.
I have already located class and method that executes creation.

[org.nodeclipse.ui\src\org\nodeclipse\ui\wizards\NodeProjectWizard.java](https://github.com/PaulVI/nodeclipse-1/blob/5995635196249cd517a5ac319031bc75e09e952a/org.nodeclipse.ui/src/org/nodeclipse/ui/wizards/NodeProjectWizard.java)

```
public class NodeProjectWizard extends Wizard implements INewWizard {
```

Where should I put my files ? I guess root of org.nodeclipse.ui project.

How to copy those files (from org.nodeclipse.ui bundle into newProjectHandle ) ?

UPDATE: What is generic answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below source file's generateTemplates() method.

[org.nodeclipse.ui\src\org\nodeclipse\ui\wizards\NodeProjectWizard.java](https://github.com/tomotaro1065/nodeclipse/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/src/org/nodeclipse/ui/wizards/NodeProjectWizard.java)

I moved README.md.template and & hello-world-server.js to org.nodeclipse.ui/templates folder.

And you can also rewrite contents of files according to the situation. See rewriteReadme() method. It rewrites "${projectname}" to the name of the project that user entered.

Comment: So for resources any folder like templates will do? It just has to be in the same module (Eclipse project), right?

Comment: You may also be able to access resources in other modules, never did myself. It might be able to do it, if you can get a bundle object from the Activator of the other module.

Answer (score -1):

You only want to include that class in your project? or have you a JAR file that you want to include?

Comment: I want to include README.md & hello-world-server.js